# Error passing wav file to IPython.display

Tags: python, scipy, jupyter-notebook, wav

I am new to Python but I am studying it as programming language for DSP. I recorded a wav file, and have been trying to play it back using `IPython.display.Audio`:

```
import IPython.display
from scipy.io import wavfile

rate, s = wavfile.read('h.wav')
IPython.display.Audio(s, rate=rate)
```

But this gives the following error:

> struct.error: ushort format requires 0 <= number <= 0xffff

[image: Error messages]

I tried installing FFmpeg but it hasn't helped.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's not a very useful error message, it took a bit of debugging to figure out what was going on!  It is caused by the "shape" of the matrix returned from `wavfile` being the wrong way around.

The docs for [`IPython.display.Audio`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.Audio) say it expects a:

> Numpy 2d array containing waveforms for each channel. Shape=(NCHAN, NSAMPLES).

If I read a (stereo) wav file I have lying around:

```
rate, samples = wavfile.read(path)
print(samples.shape)
```

I get `(141120, 2)` showing this is of shape `(NSAMPLES, NCHAN)`.  Passing this array directly to `Audio` I get a similar error as you do.  Transposing the array will flip these around, causing the array to be compatible with this method.  The transpose of a matrix in Numpy is accessed via the [`.T` attribute](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html), e.g.:

```
IPython.display.Audio(samples.T, rate=rate)
```

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, it helped me.
below is my code, maybe can help someone.

frequency = 44100
duration = 5

record = sd.rec((frequency  * duration), samplerate=frequency , channels=1, blocking=True, dtype='float64')

sd.wait()

st.audio(record.T, sample_rate=frequency)